# I am Facing Error While Installing Firestore In My React Ts Project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, syntax-error, react-tsx

## **Here Is My Code :**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCtaFhg2rHV7ZuPKFIMaisRsiNUhwSzez8",
    authDomain: "twitter-c8bcc.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "twitter-c8bcc",
    storageBucket: "twitter-c8bcc.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "951402712179",
    appId: "1:951402712179:web:9fe473631359f6f3656e06",
    measurementId: "G-7QKS23B79V"
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

export default db;
```

When I am installing npm install firebase/firestore it show me this
error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Check you have installed the latest `npm` or try updating using `npm install -g npm@latest`.
- Run `npm cache clean -f` and  Delete
  `node_modules`  and run `npm install` again.
- Check whether the `PATH`
  is correct, `cd` to `package.json` and run `npm` start.
- Or try using
  `yarn`